# How do i solve this node.js error when im calling it with jQuery?

Tags: node.js, express, web-deployment

I have this assignment and I'm a bit stuck.

When I press the button on the site the console I get this error:

> GET http://localhost:3000/getUser 404 (Not Found)  jquery-1.12.4.js:10254

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I am new to node and our teacher didn't even have any lessons on it just expects us to know it
I'm thankful for any answers I get

Here is my code:

Script.js

```
$(document).ready(() => {

$("#btn_prijava").click( () => {
    $.post('getUser', (uporabnik) => {
        console.log("Works");
    });
});
});
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const fs = require('fs');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const { request } = require('http');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.post('/getUser', (req, res) => {
    res.send("User");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("App je pognan");
});

module.exports = ap
```

Comment: Typo?  In Node you define the `/getUser` endpoint as a `POST`, but call it as a `GET`.  Which one should it be?

Comment: it should both be POST, i changed it it still doesn't work

Comment: In what way does it fail now?

Comment: The `POST /getUser` request will already be handled by the `app.use('/', indexRouter)`. Does the `indexRouter` middleware perhaps return status 404? Only if `indexRouter` calls `next()` will the `app.post('/getUser', ...)` come into play.